# How to force boost program_options to check options strictly?

Tags: c++, boost

This is my minimal example, basically copied from boost web site:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    po::options_description desc("Test options");
    desc.add_options()              
            ("help", "Print help")          
    ;
    po::variables_map vm;           
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {         
            std::cout << desc << std::endl; 
    }

}
```

When I run:

```
./main --help
```

it prints help, as expected. When I run:

```
./main --foo
```

it throws `unknown_option` error, as expected. But when I run:

```
./main foobar
```

it ignores the argument and no error is raised. I specify no positional arguments, so I expect boost to raise error here as well.

Why does boost behave this way (I expect that there is some logical reason that I don't see yet)?

What can I do to force boost to strictly check the options provided and raise error on *anything* else?

Comment: Looks like you need to provide empty `po::positional_options_description` in such case it works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bh6UDkxoTqWd48fb

Comment: @MarekR please turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.